# Can not set Windows XP Keyboard configuration

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

A friend of mine came to me with a french Windows XP where windows had decided that keyboard would now be english-US keyboard instead of french keyboard.

After a few attempts, I came to the strange conclusion that it's impossible to change it. Whatever keyboard configuration I apply, the language dialog does not complain but sticks to the english-us keyboard.

I tried :

- setting two keyboards, with FR as default
- setting two keyboards, with EN-US as default
- one keyboard as FR

It's like it was impossible to apply a new keyboard configuration. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: **1** Do you have administrator privileges?

**2** Is it a notebook with "special" keyboard settings tools?

Comment: The user has administrator privileges yes. I did not see any special keyboard setting tool but I will have a second look.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps, it should get the job done.

**Step 1 :**  In Device Manager, expand Keyboards, and then double-click the keyboard device. By default, this is Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural PS/2 Keyboard.

**Step 2 :**  Right click and then click Update Driver.

**Step 3 :** Click Browse my computer for driver software, and then click Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.

**Step 4 :** Click to clear the Show compatible hardware check box, and then click French PS/2 keyboard.

**Step 5 :** Click Next, click Yes if you receive an update driver warning message, and then follow the remaining steps to update the keyboard.

**Step 6 :** Restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Control Panel.

Step 2: Click "Date, Time, Language, and Regional Options".

Step 3: Click "Regional Options".

Step 4: Click "Languages", then "Details".

Mess around with the settings in there.

No administrator rights required.